# Sending pin to get Access token from twitter

Tags: blackberry, java-me, twitter, oauth, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using OAuth authentication to get the pin . some how i managed to get the pin from twitter by authorizing my application . But I don't know

1. how to use this pin which i got from twitter,
2. how to send this to get access token and token secret . Can any body provide me the code to get the access token . I have accesToken() method ready in my app but how to call this method while sending the pin to twitter can Any body help me with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some methods to get this auth token. See this [help1](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554724/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-oauth-access_token), [help2](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)

Comment: I can get the pin from twitter but now i want to send the pin which i got from twitter can you tell me how to do that or any source code if you can provide

Comment: have you got the access token?

Comment: i got the pin and don't no how to use that pin to get access token.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have filled in the **Callback URL:** field on https://dev.twitter.com/apps -> settings.

Note there are **several** fields: Callback URL is different to Website